# ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests while calling webservice from pl/sql procedure

Tags: web-services, plsql, oracle11g

I am invoking a webservice from PL/SQL procedure ,while executing the procedure after 5 times I am getting the below error ,any help will be appreciated.

> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1367
>   ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

Answer (score 1):

you need to close your requests once you are done with them, it does not happen automatically (unless you disconnect form the db entirely)

It used to be `utl_http.end_response`, but I am not sure if it is the same api any more. Raise an exception when there are more incoming requests as below

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN TOO_MANY_REQUESTS THEN
  END_RESPONSE(resp);
```

Comment: Actually we are not receiving any response from the webservice ,this webservice is just insert records into another table

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem , and solved it by Disconnecting from Database and reConnecting