# Viewing UTL_HTTP Open Requests

Tags: oracle, http

I'm investigating an issue where we are on occasion getting "too many open HTTP requests" error for our code using UTL_HTTP. I'm wondering where can I query a list of the open HTTP requests triggered by UTL_HTTP? I need to replicate my issue, then try various options to correct it. But without being able to view the open requests, I'm having trouble replicating.

I've looked in v$session but not seeing anything in there for the port of my request even if I don't properly close it.

Comment: Try closing connections first by calling utl_tcp.close_all_connections()

Comment: There's a hardcoded limit of 5 HTTP connections per DB session. You may be forgetting to call `utl_http.end_response` at some point. See similar questions - [example with trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235679/ora-29270-too-many-open-http-requests), [plain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070163/ora-29270-too-many-open-http-requests-while-calling-webservice-from-pl-sql-proc)

Comment: utl_http.end_response was being called, but I think I found the fix. Issue is I need to prove it. Question is, where can I "see" the open HTTP connections/requests? I need to prove out the old code is leaving some orphaned, and my fix doesn't. But I don't know how/where I can see the open HTTP requests.